# Accessing process variables from property renderer

Tags: activiti

I'm attempting to write a renderer that outputs a `select` list based upon a string array set in a previous task. In the `execute` method of the previous task I have:

```java
List<String> names =  new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Bob");
names.add("Fred");

delegate.setVariable("names", names);
```

I'm then attempting to extend `EnumFormPropertyRenderer`, and overriding `getPropertyField`:

```java
@Override
public Field getPropertyField(FormProperty formProperty) {

    ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(getPropertyLabel(formProperty));

    // Bits copied from getPropertyField in EnumFormPropertyRenderer        

    if (values != null) {
        ...
```

My issue is that I can find no way of getting access to my array `names` within `getPropertyField` - it's not part of `formProperty` that I can see, nor can I see it within  `ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine().getRuntimeService()` as I don't appear to have access to an execution ID (which is a required parameter of any call to get variables).

So - within `getPropertyField`, how can I get my array `names`? Or am I simply approaching the problem from the wrong angle in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the "ideal" solution, but the one that worked for me was to use the instance ID. At the start of the process, I added a Service Task containing the following:

```java
    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution delegate) throws Exception {

        delegate.setVariable("instanceId", delegate.getProcessInstanceId());

    }
```

During the process, my task set up the array as before, setting the variables against the current delegate:

```java
    List<String> names =  new ArrayList<String>();
    names.add("Bob");
    names.add("Fred");

    delegate.setVariable("names", names);
```

Then, when I need to display them in my drop-down, I bound it to the variable `instanceId`:

```xml
    <activiti:formProperty id="instanceId"
        name="Please select the name" type="customSelection"
        variable="instanceId" />
```

This meant that within the property renderer I could retrieve the instance ID with:

```java
    String currentInstanceId = (String) formProperty.getValue();
```

and finally retrieve my array with:

```java
    ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
    RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
    List<String> names = (List<String>) runtimeService.getVariable
        (currentInstanceId, "names");
```

for populating back into the dropdown.

The only potential issue is that it populated back into the variable `instanceId` which wasn't an issue in my case, but may be elsewhere; if the same dropdown is needed again then another call will be needed to the first Service Task to reset `instanceId`.